# How to save the multiple output of single process in publishDir in Nextflow

Tags: nextflow

I have the process  create_parallel_params whose output is parallel_params folder containing json files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.enable.dsl = 2
params.spectra = "$baseDir/data/spectra/"
params.library = "$baseDir/data/library/"
params.workflow_parameter="$baseDir/data/workflowParameters.xml"
TOOL_FOLDERS="$baseDir/bin"
process create_parallel_params{
    publishDir "$baseDir/nf_output", mode: 'copy'
    output:
    path "parallel_params/*.json"
    script:
    """
    mkdir parallel_params | python $TOOL_FOLDERS/parallel_paramgen.py \
    parallel_params \
    10 
    """
}
```

The output of the above process passed into process searchlibrarysearch_molecularv2_parallelstep1 which process each json file.

```
process searchlibrarysearch_molecularv2_parallelstep1{
    publishDir "$baseDir/nf_output", mode: 'copy'
    input:
    path json_file
    //path params.spectra
    //path params.library
    output:
    path "result_folder" emit:"result_folder/*.tsv"
    script:
    """
    mkdir result_folder convert_binary librarysearch_binary | \
    python $TOOL_FOLDERS/searchlibrarysearch_molecularv2_parallelstep1.py \
    $params.spectra \
    $json_file \
    $params.workflow_parameter \
    $params.library \
    result_folder \
    convert_binary \
    librarysearch_binary \
    
    """
}
workflow{
    ch_parallel_params=create_parallel_params()
    ch_searchlibrarysearch=searchlibrarysearch_molecularv2_parallelstep1(create_parallel_params.out.flatten())
    ch_searchlibrarysearch.view()
}
```

[image]

I want the output of these file in publishDir (nf_output) in a single folder. So How can i do that. Provide some example.

Comment: I understand that these outputs should be copied to a single folder, but what should this folder be called? And how should the outputs be arranged? If you don't want a 'result_folder' subdirectory, is there some guarantee that the contents have unique names? Do you need to output the whole folder or just the TSV files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`emit`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#process-named-output) option can be used to assign a name identifier to an output channel. This is helpful if your output declaration defines more than one output channels, but isn't usually necessary if you make only a single declaration. Providing a glob pattern as an identifier doesn't make much sense: if you need only the output TSV files (and not the whole folder), you can just use the following and the output TSV files will be published to the publishDir:

```
output:
path "result_folder/*.tsv"
```

If you want to declare the folder itself, usually you can just update your [publishDir](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#publishdir) to include a subdirectory with a unique name. You could use something like:

```
publishDir "$baseDir/nf_output/${json_file.baseName}", mode: 'copy'
```

But this will give you a 'result_folder' in every subdirectory. If that's not desirable, it might be preferable to change your output declaration to:

```
output:
path "result_folder/*"
```